# Write text to a file using testcafe

Tags: javascript, file, testing, testcafe, writefile

I was wondering if there's a way I can create a file and save the data in a file using testcafe.

```
test('copy data', async t => {
  await someAction(t);
  const data = RequestLogger(data, { logRequestBody: true, stringifyRequestBody: true });
  await t.clearContent('data/output.js');
  await t.writeText('data/output.js', data);
});
```

I have written some dummy test to explain what I need. Is it possible to do something of this sort in testcafe? How could we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely treat a testcafe test as a nodejs application where you can use any standard nodejs API and/or any other third-party modules to write/read files:

[How do I write files in Node.js?](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/how-to-write-files-in-nodejs/)

[Import Third-Party Modules](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/import-third-party-modules)

Comment: Ah! Why didn't I think of that! Thank you :)